# Angular - ng2-charts - Título no eixo x

Tags: angular, gráfico

Estou utilizando (ng2-charts) para implementar um gráfico em barras, e no momento, estou tentando incluir um título com a porcentagem no eixo x (como na imagem abaixo) e estou encontrando dificuldades. Alguém poderia me ajudar? É possível?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O ng2-charts utiliza o Chart.js. Você encontra muitos exemplos [aqui](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/).

Agora fica a dúvida do que exatamente você quer mostar no eixo x. Se for o valor medido, você pode usar [esse plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels). Na [página de exemplos](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/samples/formatting/custom-labels.html) tem um que talvez seja parecido com o que você quer.

Após instalar o plugin, basta criar o gráfico com a opção do label:

```
var chart = new Chart('chart-0', {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: Samples.color(0),
                    data: Samples.numbers({
                        count: DATA_COUNT,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100
                    })
                }]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        align: 'end',
                        anchor: 'end',
                        font: function(context) {
                            var w = context.chart.width;
                            return {
                                size: w < 512 ? 12 : 14
                            }
                        },
                        formatter: function(value, context) {
                            return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
                        }
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: false,
                        offset: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```